# SolrException: Error opening new searcher

Tags: java, indexing, solr

I have Solr on my computer and it was working fine up until yesterday. When I start it up, I get SolrCore Initialization Failures for every core. The error is

`org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher`

This is the full stack trace:

```
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:885)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:652)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:518)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:283)
at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:277)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Error opening new searcher
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1577)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.getSearcher(SolrCore.java:1689)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:857)
... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to unmap the mapped buffer: MMapIndexInput(path="D:\solr-5.1.0\solr-5.1.0\server\solr\kofax_fxm_master\data\index\segments_2b")
at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2.freeBuffer(MMapDirectory.java:301)
at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.freeBuffer(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:378)
at org.apache.lucene.store.ByteBufferIndexInput.close(ByteBufferIndexInput.java:357)
at org.apache.lucene.store.BufferedChecksumIndexInput.close(BufferedChecksumIndexInput.java:60)
at org.apache.lucene.index.SegmentInfos.readCommit(SegmentInfos.java:413)
at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.<init>(IndexWriter.java:826)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.<init>(SolrIndexWriter.java:78)
at org.apache.solr.update.SolrIndexWriter.create(SolrIndexWriter.java:65)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.createMainIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:273)
at org.apache.solr.update.DefaultSolrCoreState.getIndexWriter(DefaultSolrCoreState.java:116)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.openNewSearcher(SolrCore.java:1546)
... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: class org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2$1 cannot access class jdk.internal.ref.Cleaner (in module java.base) because module java.base does not export jdk.internal.ref to unnamed module @2c718865
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.Reflection.newIllegalAccessException(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(Unknown Source)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2$1.run(MMapDirectory.java:294)
at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2$1.run(MMapDirectory.java:286)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory$2.freeBuffer(MMapDirectory.java:286)
... 20 more
```

I tried deleting all of my cores and starting fresh, I wiped out and reinstalled solr, but the error persists.

Comment: Did you upgrade your JVM to a version not supported by the version of Solr you have installed?

Comment: I don't think I've upgraded recently... I'm on version 9.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you are running the wrong version of Java. I see from your error you're on 5.1 but your notes say you're version 9 of java, if you roll it back to 8 it will fix the issue.

Comment: I uninstalled Java 9 and installed 8 and it's working now!